# Draw disk using Triangle Fan mode

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw a disk using triangle_fan mode but my disk is draw with a part missing near his end (the disk is not fully draw, something like 320 degrees is visible).

Here is what I've got:

```
int vertexCount = 40;

// Vertices
float radius = 0.5f;
positions.push_back(vec3(0, 0, 0));
for( int a = 0; a < 360; a += 360 / vertexCount )
{
     double heading = a * M_PI / 180.f;
     positions.push_back(vec3(cos(heading) * radius, sin(heading) * radius, 0));
}

// Indices
int indiceCount = positions.size(); 
for( int i = 0; i < indiceCount; i++ )
    indices.push_back(i);

indices.push_back(1);
```

Comment: Similar problem happened to me when I had wrong sizes of array passed to OpenGL functions filling buffer objects or drawing it. I recommend checking this sections of code too. Generation of shape looks correct. Also i recommend changing a to floating-point type (it wont break for).

Comment: Try <= 360.  You want the last one to connect to the first.

Comment: @Robinson I suppose, that this last connection is done by "indices.push_back(1);"

Comment: Should be push_back(0) I would have thought.

Comment: @Robinson No. Zero is middle point. This is, what this code [achieve](http://zone.ni.com/images/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/noloc_eps_tri_fan.gif)

Comment: Quite right.  I'll go back to sleep :p.

Comment: Can you share your rendering code?